# How to put logs into mysql table?

Tags: python, mysql, sql

I want to save my logs in a mysql database. So i created this function to put in a string and then the function format the string into a sql injection and execute it. But it always fails.

My table:
[image]

Function:

```
def log(string):
    sqlFormula = f'INSERT INTO logs (log) VALUES (%s)'
    string = f'({string})'
    mycursor.execute(sqlFormula, string)
    mydb.commit()
```

Comment: What does _it always fails_ mean? Fails how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `execute` function takes a tuple, but you're making a string with brackets in it. This isn't the same thing.

Instead:

```
def log(string):
    sqlFormula = 'INSERT INTO logs (log) VALUES (%s)'
    mycursor.execute(sqlFormula, (string,))
    mydb.commit()
```

Even better, ditch that single-use variable which serves no purpose:

```
def log(string):
    mycursor.execute('INSERT INTO logs (log) VALUES (%s)', (string,))
    mydb.commit()
```

Answer (score 0):

The second argument to `mycursor.execute()` should be a list or tuple, not a string. You make a tuple by wrapping parentheses around the variable, and adding a comma if it's just one element, not by creating a string that contains parentheses.

```
def log(string):
    sqlFormula = f'INSERT INTO logs (log) VALUES (%s)'
    mycursor.execute(sqlFormula, (string,))
    mydb.commit
```